# Access violation in GHCI

Tags: haskell, ffi, ghci

I have a Haskell program using the FFI to import C++ functions. I'm using Windows. When I compile to an executable or to a DLL, this works. But when I load a module in GHCI, this doesn't always work: sometimes this works, sometimes I get *Access violation in generated code when reading 0000000000000000* whenever I call a function from the module (even if this function has nothing to do with the C++). Do you know how to prevent that?

Comment: This is quite vague - you ahould include a minimal example which shows the problem. Note, for FFI to work at all in GHCi you must pass `-fobejct-code`. However, without this option the error you will get is different, so I don't know if this is your problem.

Comment: @user2407038 Yep, sorry for the vagueness but this problem doesn't occur for a small code. My code is [here](https://github.com/stla/owenqp) but I'm afraid nobody will look at such a piece of code.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, if small code works, and large code doesn't, start simplifying the large code you have until it works.  It might even show you exactly what the problem is

Comment: @luqui That's what I did previously. But that does not lead to anything because of the random behavior. Currently my program works like a charm in GHCI.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, oh man, I didn't notice "doesn't always work". Maybe try loading up `ghci` in `gdb` so you can see where it goes wrong specifically (hoping that it's in the C++ code)?