# Access violation error While trying to run a simple Yesod program on Windows 10

Tags: haskell, yesod, haskell-stack

I am trying to run a few basic Haskell snippets on a windows 10 machine with GHC Version 8.2.2 via Stack tool. I get the following access violation error:

```
e:\reset\as>stack runghc a.hs
stack runghc a.hs
Access violation in generated code when executing data at ffffffffac0039e0
```

the contents of "a.hs" are:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies     #-}

import Yesod

data HelloWorld = HelloWorld

mkYesod "HelloWorld" [parseRoutes|
/ HomeR GET
|]

instance Yesod HelloWorld

getHomeR :: Handler Html
getHomeR = defaultLayout [whamlet|Hello World!|]

main :: IO()
main = warp 3000 HelloWorld
```

I was able to get a few results in return to my google-fu, but I don't think there is a proper solution for this version of ghci:

temporary solution: [Haskell-Stack: Access violation error during build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48232637/haskell-stack-access-violation-error-during-build)

violation on GHC 8.0.2: https://github.com/hedgehogqa/haskell-hedgehog/issues/111

works while compiling to dll: [Access violation in GHCI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47849032/access-violation-in-ghci)

Is there an explanation for why this error occurs, and how I can avoid it?

Edit: @epsilonhable asked if compiling works; I tried it, it compiles and runs with no issues.

```
e:\dir\reset\as>stack ghc a.hs
stack ghc a.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( a.hs, a.o )
Linking a.exe ...


e:\HiHenry\reset\as>
e:\HiHenry\reset\as>a.exe
a.exe
01/Feb/2018:15:59:07 +0530 [Info#yesod-core] Application launched @(yesod-core-1.4.37.3-JVciWQSLH8J1mylGVdkmic:Yesod.Core.Dispatch .\Yesod\Core\Dispatch.hs:166:11)
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Feb/2018:15:59:50 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 82 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Feb/2018:15:59:50 +0530] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 118 "http://127.0.0.1:3001/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"
```

Running it via interpreter(stack runghc a.hs) still results in an access violation.

Comment: Does it work when you compile instead of interpreting it?

Comment: @epsilonhalbe, yes it does!

Comment: @epsilonhalbe, yes it does!
    e:\dir\reset\as>stack ghc a.hs
    stack ghc a.hs
    [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( a.hs, a.o )
    Linking a.exe ...
    
    
    e:\HiHenry\reset\as>
    e:\HiHenry\reset\as>a.exe
    a.exe
    01/Feb/2018:15:59:07 +0530 [Info#yesod-core] Application launched @(yesod-core-1.4.37.3-JVciWQSLH8J1mylGVdkmic:Yesod.Core.Dispatch .\Yesod\Core\Dispatch.hs:166:11)
    127.0.0.1 - - [01/Feb/2018:15:59:50 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 82 ""

Comment: Does GHCi work _at all_ (without a module like `a.hs`)?

Comment: @leftaroundabout, yes it does, a simple hello world program works fine.

Comment: Often antivirus software can cause problems with GHC-generated code. In particular `HitmanPro` is a known offender. You may want to try after disabling such AV.

Comment: hey @sclv, tried to disable Symantec end point protection on my machine and retry, still the same error. I don't have hitmanpro installed.

Comment: one other workaround is the `-fexternal-interpreter` flag. Not sure what else could be at issue...